por que mi vista no se muestra?
tengo mi controlador de Home y el orden de las carpetas es asi Views > Home --(adentro de home) --> Formulario.cshtml , Confirmacion.cshtml , adjunto condigo de controlador  , basicamente es un boton que inserta un aviso y posterior de ahi , me deberia enviar a la vista de Confirmacion , ya lo intente con RedirectToAction pero aun asi no me funciono que puedo estar haciendo mal?
Repito , ambas vistas estan en al carpeta de Home y estos metodos de accion que regresan la vista tambien lo estan en dichas carpetas
el codigo es mucho mas largo , pero solo dejare lo importante
public IActionResult InsertaAviso()
{
  return View("Confirmacion");
}



public IActionResult Confirmacion()
 {
    return View();
 }


Te sugiero revisar los nombre que esten correctos, por ejemplo, si estás retornando una vista llamada "Confirmacion" debes tner un archivo llamado "Confirmacion.cshtml", y debe estar dentro de la carpeta "Views/Home".
